# JQuery Select few option of multi-select on click of another checkbox

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to select few values of the multiple select box options on click of another checkbox using jquery. This select box uses multiselect filter plugin.

```
<h3 class="accordion_head">
            <a href="#">Company Region</a><span class="bg arrow"></span>
        </h3>
        <div class="accordion_body">
            <ul>    
                <li><input id="companyRegion1" name="companyRegion" value="GCC" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="companyRegion1">GCC</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And the second select box I follows spring tag as below

```
<form:select path="${elementPath }" multiple="multiple" cssClass="multi_select">
    <form:options items="${valueList}" itemLabel="${label}" itemValue="${itemVal }" />
</form:select>
```

So when clicking on the checkbox mentioned above I need to preselect GCC countries in the multiple select box. this is implemeted using [multiselect jquery plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter)

I have tried this way but it is not getting selected.

```
$('#companyCountries option[value=247]').prop('selected',true);
```

Please help.

Comment: What error you getting in ur console ?

Comment: @surajrawat no error in console, the options not getting selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by calling the refresh as mentioned in the [multi-select plugin site.](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh)
I couldn't invoke by form name, so removed form name.

```
$("#companyCountries").multiselect('refresh');
```

Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

The Code for checking the check box is as below for JQuery 1.6 and above. 
The JQuery versions below you have check with api documentation [$.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
`$('#CompaniesSearchForm countries option[value=247]').prob('checked',true);`
```